# Restrict Users from Selecting Calendars in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I've just migrated a client to Office 365 Small Business Premium (Outlook 2013). We've create 4 additional calendars online and then selected them on the machines we've hooked up to that account. What we want to do is disable the ability to select or deselect specific calendars from the list that is provided on the calendar page. We need to do this so his personal calendar cannot be selected on any system that is attached to his online Exchange account.

I've searched for a registry setting, the closest I've come is

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Preferences\CalendarSelection`

The problem is the only reference I've found for this is for Outlook 2007 (so I'm not sure it still exists) and I can't find any reference to what that does.

Does anyone know of a registry setting that will disable that ability? The computers are in a workgroup.